# Directly Getting View Information/Records in Lotus Notes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Basically I need to access some records or data from a view in lotus notes itself. I can't use use the `@DBLookup` since our target is not to refresh the form. I know that using AJAX it is possible though I still haven't tried AJAX yet if you have a detailed tutorial please share it here.

My main question is basically any other easier way to access these records in the view? Directly coding in the javascript part of a field. Thanks a lot.

Basically `@DbLookup` = "?" Javascript (Not AJAX).

Comment: You've tagged this as lotus-notes. Since Javascript exists in both, please clarify: Is this a web browser app or a Notes client app? It really should have the lotus-domino tag if it's a web app.

Comment: It is a web application Richard. Ok sorry for that will include it too. Thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do like Torsten is suggesting, create a Lotusscript agent that performs the lookup and returns a JSON object with the data. You then make an Ajax-call to that agent from your webpage using Javascript or (even easier) jQuery.

I posted some code on my blog a while back. It is doing something similar, but instead of performing a view lookup, it retrieves the values of a specific document based on a document ID. You can find the code and a more detailed explanation here:
http://blog.texasswede.com/code-snippet-jquery/

This is the jQuery code:

```
function loadNotesFields(docunid) {
    var notesfieldname = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: "/database.nsf/ajax_GetNotesFieldFields?OpenAgent", 
        data: {"NotesUNID":docunid},
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('input[notesfield]').each(function() {
            notesfieldname = $(this).attr("notesfield");
            $(this).val(data[notesfieldname]);
        });
    });
}
```

And this is the Lotusscript code:

```
Dim urldata List as String
Sub Initialize
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim webform As NotesDocument
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim urlstring As String
    Dim urlarr As Variant
    Dim urlvaluename As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim json As String

    Set webform = session.DocumentContext
    '*** Remove leading "OpenAgent" from Query_String
    urlstring = StrRight(webform.Query_String_Decoded(0),"&")
    '*** Create list of arguments passed to agent
    urlarr = Split(urlstring,"&")
    For i = LBound(urlarr) To UBound(urlarr)
        urlvaluename = Split(urlarr(i),"=")
        urldata(urlvaluename(0)) = urlvaluename(1)
    Next
    Set thisdb = session.CurrentDatabase
    '*** Create content header for return data
    Print "content-type: application/json"
    '*** Get Notes document baed on NotesUIND argument
    Set doc = db.GetDocumentByUNID(urldata("NotesUNID"))
    '*** Build JSON for all fields in document except $fields
    json = "{" + Chr$(13)
    ForAll item In doc.Items
        If Left$(item.Name,1)<>"$" Then
            json = json + |"| + item.Name + |":"| + item.Text + |",|+ Chr$(13)
        End If
    End ForAll
    '*** Remove trailing comma and line break
    json = Left$(json,Len(json)-2)  
    json = json + "}"
    '*** Return JSON
    Print json  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Karl, Thanks for the information. I went through it and studied the jquery itself. I had a hard time at first but now I gained new knowledge since jquery and ajax are not used by me at all before.

Comment: Hi Karl, Is this working on IE and Google Chrome? It's fine in FF but on the other two it's not? Thanks

Comment: Yes, jQuery works in IE and Chrome. What version of jQuery are you using, and what version of the browsers are you testing with?
The code above is working in IE 10 for me, using jQuery 1.10.1 (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Hi Karl, I first used jQuery 1.11.1 then I converted it to 1.10.1 now still it doesn't work. It works in FF but not in IE and Chrome. I am directly calling the js from the main website of jquery. My codes is like this... $.ajax({
 url: strURL
})
.done(function(data) {"Here I am filling up the values of a combo box"}); ---- It works in FF but it also takes time it takes around 9-15 secs depnding on the speed of the net.. Thanks I hope you can help me.

Comment: Hi Karl, I was able to make it work. My mistake is that I am directly connecting to the "http", where in it should be "https" something related to security. Maybe for safety purpose will copy the js to my notes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you use a CDN you should exclude the "http:" part of the url, then it will work no matter which protocol your page use. E.g. <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Okay Karl, Noted, will keep that in mind. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If that were an XPages- question, then the answer would be easy: Use the JavaScript @DBLookup.

For "classic" web- development it is not that easy. You need to write an agent, that gives you back the result of the @DBLookup in whatever format you want and call that agent using an ajax- call. That would look like this:

LotusScript- Agent, trigger none

```
Dim ses as New NotesSession
Dim db as NotesDatabase
Dim viw as NotesView
Dim dc as NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc as NotesDocument

Set db = ses.CurrentDatabase
Set viw = db.GetView( "YourLookupView" )
Set dc = viw.GetAllDocumentsByKey( "YourLookupKey" )
Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument
While not doc is Nothing
  Print doc.GetItemValue( "NameOfItemToReturn" )(0)
  Set doc = dc.GetNextDocument( doc )
Wend
```

This agent will return a "page" with all values, one line each.. in your ajax- return- function you then do, what you want to with this values.

Usually you do not simply print values, but return json- object, or some xml- structure, or already html as ordered list, or whatever, but the principle should be clear.

Then you call the agent (e.g. with an ajax- call) like: hxxp://server/db.nsf/AgentName?OpenAgent

Another possibility would be to use an url like `hxxp://server/db.nsf/YourLookupView?ReadViewEntries&restricttocategory=YourCategory` or `hxxp://server/db.nsf/YourLookupView?ReadViewEntries&restricttocategory=YourCategory&OutputFormat=json` and parse the result with "native" javascript...

Comment: Alright, Thanks for the information torsten, studied the link of karl henry.